# UITableView Row Selection Returns Wrong Index Path Until Scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

Xcode 7.3 / Swift 2.2 / iOS 9.3 (sim) and 9.3.1 (device)

I am using a view controller with two child view controllers. It is meant to function like a navigation menu (source: https://github.com/ArtisOracle/SASlideDrawer).

I have two sections in the navigation view controller's table view. The first time the navigation view controller is loaded, when I try to tap a table view cell, the tap selects the row that is about two cell heights *below* the actually selected cell. The top image part is a different section from the bottom list part, but that does not seem to matter much.

It seems to be getting the index path of the incorrectly selected cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In other words, the index path that I *expect* I am selecting is **not** the `indexPath` that is the argument to didSelectRow.

I can fix the issue by rubber banding the table view content off screen and letting it drag back. Then the selection works normally. This is occurring both on device and on the simulator.

This video demo explains this a bit better:

[image: Screen capture of issue]

Thank you for reading and look forward to your help.

Comment: have you actually checked the indexes for the rows, if they are correct? You might need to reload your tableView again on viewDidAppear when your slide panel is showing up...cause I think this is what happening on your scroll, and it looks like it fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks. That actually has solved the issue... I thought I had already tried that of all debug steps. I am flabbergasted that is what is needed to fix it, not `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`. Can you write that as an answer?

Comment: Just did, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually checked the indexes for the rows, if they are correct?

You might need to reload your tableView again on viewDidAppear when your slide panel is showing up...cause I think this is what happening on your scroll, and it looks like it fixes your issue.